# Rails best practices - Parameter or polymorphic model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have two models : `Ownership` and `Loan`.

In order to validate the transaction, I use boolean on both models : `current`, `agreed`, `available`. But it may be redundant. So I'm asking myself if I should create another model, let's call it `status`, with this three booleans, and add polymorphic associations with Ownership and Loan.

What do you think about it ? Should I delete the boolean from both models and create a polymorphic model which contains each boolean ? Or should I keep it my way ?

Comment: I generally use state machines with a mere status field. State machines are are a great way to organize events/callbacks

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will read that. But if I don't use state machine (I'm a newbie at coding), what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need a `polymorphic` association here, but moving those fields to a separate model sounds like a good idea since it appears from your description that this can be a simple lookup table.

I would create a `Status` model and define those three attributes as such:

```
# Schema Information
# id     :integer   not null, primary key
# status :string(8) not null 
#

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  CURRENT = find_by_status('current')
  AGREED = find_by_status('agreed')
  AVAILABLE = find_by_status('available')
end
```

Then in your `Ownership` and `Loan` models I would add a `status_id` field which hold's the `Status.id`.  And you would access these status constants as `Status::CURRENT` and so on.

Comment: what are those constants?

Comment: @apneadiving, Those are the boolean fields the OP has in the two models.  Your idea of state machines sounds interesting.  Could you show a quick sample?

Comment: your constants seem to contain the result of an active record query which is very weir

Comment: @apneadiving, True, I'd want to store these in a database table.